# Retrieving certain fields from a json.parse to use as a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to retrieve all the data from certain objects within a JavaScript array; however I'm having trouble pulling that data.  This is the array structure:

```
{\"responses\":[{\"responseId\":\"R_54lNG4hW4m0ULsi\",\"values\":{\"startDate\":\"2021-08-19T20:36:50.190Z\",\"endDate\":\"2021-08-19T20:36:50.190Z\",\"status\":4,\"finished\":1,\"recordedDate\":\"2021-08-19T20:36:50.190Z\",\"_recordId\":\"R_54lNG4hW4m0ULsi\",\"QID1_TEXT\":\"08/19/2021\",\"QID2_TEXT\":\"\",\"QID3_TEXT\":\"\",\"QID4_TEXT\":\"\",\"QID8_TEXT\":\"\",\"QID5_TEXT\":\"10\",\"QID6_TEXT\":\"Test \",\"QID7_TEXT\":\"\"},\"labels\":{\"status\":\"Imported\",\"finished\":\"True\"},\"displayedFields\":[],\"displayedValues\":{}},
```

This is my code:

```
for (var key in GetData.responses) {
  var obj = GetData.responses[key].values;
  for (var value in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
      var ObjA = (obj[key]);
      document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = ObjA;
      console.log(ObjA);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to loop over all the objects beginning with QID1 and pull the value, but I'm missing something.  As you can see from the json, there's a number of fields I need to filter out.  I'm just getting stuck in the weeds.

Comment: Please no [screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Show the actual structure. Call `JSON.stringify(yourData, null, 2)` and paste it into the question as a code block. If it's too big to fit, just grab a couple of rows that represent the data as a whole and elide any unnecessary properties. Thanks.

Comment: Please put your Data object in text form here so it can be reproduced somewhere.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. But you keep overwriting the same element's `innerHTML`, so at the end you'll just get the last property in the `values` object.

Comment: You'll also loop over the properties like `status` and `_recordId`. If you just want the `QIDx_TEXT` properties, you'll need to check whether `key` starts with `QID`.

Comment: Is `Object.entries(d.responses[0].values).filter(([k, v]) => k.startsWith("QID")).map(([k, v]) => v)`  what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like following snippet (just little modification of your code):

```js
const responses = [
  {
    values: {
      QID1_text: 1,
      QID2_text: 1212,
    }
  },
  {
    values: {
      QID1_text: 2,
      QID2_text: 1212,
    }
  },
  {
    values: {
      QID1_text: 3,
      QID2_text: 1212,
    }
  },
]
const text = document.querySelector("#container")
const regEx = /^QID1/;
for (let key in responses) {
  let obj = responses[key].values;
  for (let value in obj) {
    if (regEx.test(value)) {
      let ObjA = (obj[value]);
      let p = document.createElement("p");
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.setAttribute('data', ObjA);
      p.innerHTML = ObjA;
      div.appendChild(p);
      text.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="container"></p>
```

Comment: If I wanted to display those results in separate divs for example <p>1</p> <p>2</p>.  How would I go about that?

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to add a parent div around each record, so if I show all fields it would wrap each record with a parent div?

Comment: Yeah, I checked it, to pull in all the fields I used QID to pull in all qid fields.  I noticed it only wrapped individual divs, but do you know a way to wrap all the records in one div?  I'm currently slicing it using every 8th div wrap it, but if I can wrap it before it renders that would be perfect.  Thank you so much for your help on this.